# How to change color in StackLayout?

Tags: c#, android, xaml

I developing app with Visual Studio to `Android`, and I have file `ItemsPage.xaml` with this code :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="General" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="5">
                            <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="ST:" /><Label Text = "{Binding ST_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                            <Label Text="Folio:" /><Label Text = "{Binding Folio_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                                <Label Text="txt" /><Label Text = "{Binding Sent} " FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And in my `ItemsPage.xaml.cs` I can't access to my `StackLayout` with `Name="General"`, I need paint this with color, but I can't, please help.

In general I can't do General.Background, I don't know access this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements inside a `DataTemplate` are not accessible from outside the `DataTemplate`; this includes the code-behind (the `xaml.cs` file).

`DataTemplates` are handled in a special way. They're used as a template (hence the name) for each item inside the `ListView`. This means that at runtime there's going to be an instance of the contents inside the `DataTemplate` for each item. If you have 20 items in that list, there's going to be 20 `StackLayout`s with the name `General`. You can read about `DataTemplates` in the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/).

If you want to set the background color of the `StackLayout`, the easiest way is to do that directly on the `StackLayout` element:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="General" BackgroundColor="Blue" Orientation="Horizontal"...
```

Alternatively you can create a `ContentView` and put that inside the `ViewCell`. The `BindingContext` of the `ContentView` will automatically be set to the current item. `ContentView`s are a bit like `ContentPage`s, but you can use them inside a page like any other `View` (like a `Button` or a `BoxView`.

**Edit**

To add a `ContentView` right-click and add a new file, choose *ContentView*. Put the XAML inside `ViewCell` inside the `ContentView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Testing.MyView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="General" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Padding="5">
            <Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 " />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="ST:" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ST_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40" />
                <Label Text="Folio:" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Folio_string}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40" />
                <Label Text="txt" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Sent} " FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

In the code-behind, you can access all controls:

```
public partial class MyView : ContentView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        General.BackgroundColor = true ? Color.Blue : Color.Brown;
    }
}
```

Then add the `ContentView` to the `ViewCell`:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <local:MyView/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: But I need modify BackgroundColor in some cases, you should explain me solution alternatively as it seems to be what I need.

Comment: You can get started by looking at this short tutorial: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/ In essence, a `ContentView` is just like a `ContentPage`, but you can put the `ContentView` inside a page